# Netlogo hide-turtle

Tags: hide, netlogo, turtle-graphics

Here's a Netlogo-beginner question. I created a model where birds shall fly on a certain route. I created this route by placing 10 turtles I called "rasts" (resting place) on patches an linking them with each other. Now, I want to make the birds fly on these routes and when a resting place disappears (by using an "on/off"-switch), they shall take another route. 
My problem: At the moment I have 5 rasts but only the first one can be shut off by using the switch. Has anybody an idea, how to fix this?

Here's my code:

```
breed [rasts rast]
breed [birds bird]

to setup
 setup-rasts
 hide-rasts1 
 hide-rasts2 
 hide-rasts3 
 hide-rasts4
 hide-rasts5
end 

to setup-rasts
 set-default-shape rasts "circle"                  
 create-rasts 1 [setxy -12 36 ]
end

to hide-rasts1                                        
 ifelse rast-1? [ ask rast (number-of-birds + 0) [ set hidden? true] ]
               [ ask rast (number-of-birds + 0) [ set hidden? false] ]
end
```

Comment: Bergant has given a good answer for the hide-turtle part. Can you please ask a separate and specific question for following the route?

Comment: I have 3 routes builded out of links. Each route contains 4 "rasts". Now, the birds shall follow a route (move from rast1 to rast2) until a "rast" disappears.  When a rast disappears the birds have to search another near-by-"rast" ,but they should not move back to their first resting place.

Comment: I put the code for the movement of the turtles in my question, now. ;-)

Comment: Please start a new question, do not ask new questions in comments. The point of StackOverflow is to create a resource. Therefore, the title, question and answer should match each other and be specific so other people also get the benefit of your question.

Answer (score 2):

For the first question:

> 1. Isn't it possible to make more than 1 turtle hide itself by using the
>      following code?

you can ask a list of turtles to hide:

```
; hide all turtles
ask turtles [ hide-turtle ]
; hide all your "rasts"
ask rasts[ hide-turtle ]
; hide random 4 of your turtles
ask n-of 4 turtles [ hide-turtle ]
```

As for the 2. question

> 2. Is it possible to make turtles (birds) follow a route an change it,
>      when there's another turtle (rast) in there way?

the answer is *of course it is possible*, but the question is somehow to general to suggest a precise solution. You can use the [`face`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#face) command to point the turtle in the right direction. For sensing the nearest turtles check the turtles with min distance. For example (in turtle's context):

```
set nearest-rast min-one-of (other rasts) [ distance myself ]
```